# Unable to access object item inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access orderid from the following response:

```
[{"response":"true","orderid":"30438","lineitemid":"34048"}]
```

Please help!

Comment: `yourObj[0].orderid`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be useful

```
var a = [{"response":"true","orderid":"30438","lineitemid":"34048"}];
var orderId = a[0].orderid;
document.write('<pre>'+orderId+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/s3vhevot/)

Comment: undefined coming for me

Comment: what is undefined?

Comment: I have done the same with alert, in alert I am getting undefined

Comment: I the success of ajax I am getting the value:

Comment: success : function(result){
    
        alert(result[0].orderid);

Comment: Could it be possible that you did not Concert the response String to an object by using JSON.parse(STRING) ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var obj = [{"response":"true","orderid":"30438","lineitemid":"34048"}];
var id = obj[0]["orderid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with parsing the result in json.
I have used `jQuery.parseJSON()` and then it is working fine.